# Center navigation bar items (links and image)

Tags: html, css

so I'm recreating Apple's webpage (not exactly the same, but I'm taking some of their design) and I would like to center the navigation bar items.

I tried using text-align and align (center), but it does nothing, I think it's probably because it's a fixed bar, but I don't what it causes it not to align to the center.

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wsjkkLpL/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Apple - iPhone</title>
```

```
<ul>
    <img src="images/logo.png">
    <li><a href="#">iPhone</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Mac</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">iPad</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">iPod</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="ad">

    <center>
    <h3 class="blackh1">iPhone</h3>
    <h2 class="blackh1">This is 7.</h2>
    <img src="images/iphone.jpg" class="iphoneimg">
    </center>

</div>
<div id="product-container">
    <div id="product" class="product2">

        <h1 class="whiteh1">iPhone</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.</p>

    </div>
    <div id="product" class="product1">

        <h1 class="blueh1">iPad</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.</p>

    </div>
</div>
<div id="product-container2">

</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `float: left` on `li` is causing this. You can use:

- `display: inline-block` – `<li>`s will be "treated like text", so `text-align: center` works (https://jsfiddle.net/v7p9wjgt/)…
- …or flexbox (https://jsfiddle.net/0krucs4w/), which might be handy in case you want to change the layout on narrow/mobile screens etc.

Comment: Thanks! Flexbox did it for me, as I'm going to change the layout between devices!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using `float: left` on your `<li>` element. Swap that to `display: inline-block`, and then set a `text-align: center` on your `<ul>`. You'll also need to move your image to within an `<li>` block itself:

```
<li><img src="images/logo.png"></li>

ul {
  text-align: center;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

I've created a working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Obsidian_Age/ys1L10n3/).

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

you just needed to make the ul text-align:center, and then remove the float-left from the li, and replace it with display: inline-block.

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wsjkkLpL/1/

If you want something vertically aligned, floating left/right isn't going to work.

Further reading: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar.asp

```
ul {
list-style-type: none;
background-color: rgba(10,10,10,0.85);
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```